# is it possible to map images to a color ramp node?

Tags: materials, uv, geometry-nodes, image

I have just finished this tutorial by Ilir Beqiri 'Dynamic, Recursive Subdivision With Geometry Nodes'. It has moving pieces that have different colors on them. I have managed to get image texture on them by using the UV map output on the grid node. But I would like to have  multiple images on each square instead of one. He did this with a *Color Ramp* node. Is there a way to do this using image textures?

[image: the material]
[image: the geonode setup]

Here is the blend file with the picture using the UV map. I basically would like to be able to have multiple pictures on the grid but I'm not sure how...

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/ ? How do you want to place your images for one color ? Each square contains one full image VS squares are only the same image all together VS something else ?

Comment: As you can see the _Color Ramp_ only has a _Fac_ input which only accepts float values (which will be greyscale when coming from an image) in the 0 to 1 range. So it does not take color images as input (well it does, but converts them to greyscale). The sliders you can set can only be given a single color value for each slider. So the only thing I can imagine is using a stepped greyscale output which is then used for mixing different textures. But the _Color Ramp_ itself cannot output image textures.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DgEVxJJ2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DgEVxJJ2/) here is the blend file with the picture using the uv map. I basically would like to be able to have multiple pictures on the grid but im not sure how...

Comment: Thank you for taking an interest Lutzi and thank you Gordon at least I know now I cant use the color ramp to do it